# javascript onclick null in custom js file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to simply detect clicking an A link to display an Alert box. Whenever I place the script inside the php file my a link is located, it works fine, but whenever I place it in my custom JS file, it doesn't detect it, and I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError : Cannot set property "onclick" of null'.

The link between the php page and custom js page is definitely working, as I have previous working code on the page. It simply wont detect my A link it its located in an external script.

HTML

```
<a id="ConfirmHolidayClose" href="#">
    <img src="assets/img/close-button.png" alt="Holiday-request-close-button" 
        class="CloseButton" />
</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById("ConfirmHolidayClose").onclick=function(){
    alert("Working");
}
```

UPDATE - Forgot to mention sorry, my a link is nested inside div called 'ConfirmHoliday'.

I have JS code manipulating the ConfirmHoliday div inside my Custom JS, so it cant be loading after because it is finding its parent div perfectly well at the moment.

Comment: are you loading your js before the element?

Comment: It's trying to access the ConfirmHolidayClose element before it exists maybe? Where is your JS loaded in your page? I'm guessing in your <head>

Comment: Write your script inside window.onload function

Comment: Please show your HTML headers. Especially how you include the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript file runs before the element is created, thus it doesn't exist. To solve this, you have couple options:

1) Surround the code with a `window.onload` function

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Your code here
};
```

2) Put it in a separate js file and add a defer property to the script tag.

```
<script src="yourScript.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

3) Put the script tag after the anchor tag

Comment: window.onload is not correct - that will wait until the entire page has loaded, we just want to wait for the DOM to load

Comment: @Zinc he currently encapsulates an image with the anchor tag, if the image isn't loaded, then you can't click it

Comment: In this case, good point - but that is a separate issue, if he sets the image dimensions (which he should) then this is a non issue as placeholder will exist in the DOM.

Comment: @Zinc Well, 1) we're trying to solve his current problem, in which using a DOM load event isn't useful, 2) if he sets the dimensions (which he should as you say) the image still needs to load. I don't know about you, but I never started clicking random empty spots on webpages because there may be an image there with an onclick function attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to access the ConfirmHolidayClose element before it exists maybe? Where is your JS loaded in your page? I'm guessing in your `<head>`

A few solutions:

1) Move your script to bottom of page just above `</body>`

2) wrap your JS in dom ready function, this ensures no JS will run until the DOM tree exists. Easiest with jQuery, example below...

**jQuery example**

```
$(function() {

    document.getElementById("ConfirmHolidayClose").onclick=function(){
        alert("Working");
    }

});
```

**Vanilla example**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  document.getElementById("ConfirmHolidayClose").onclick=function(){
        alert("Working");
    }

});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use html tags in uppercase. It's against XHTML